# Python decorator cause Flask RunTimeError

Tags: python, flask, runtime-error, decorator

I have the following function, using a custom decorator `custom_overload` :

```
@bp.route('/login', defaults={'fallback': None}, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@bp.route('/login?fallback=<path:fallback>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@custom_overload(function='auth.register', file=__file__)
def login(fallback):
    print('here')
    custom = get_custom_id()
    if fallback is not None:
        fallback = fallback.replace('%', '/')
    else:
        fallback = url_for('pdf.index', time='TODAY')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        db = get_db()
        error = None
        user = db.execute(
            'SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?', (username,)
        ).fetchone()

        if user is None:
            error = gettext('USERNAME_REQUIRED')
        elif not check_password_hash(user['password'], password):
            error = gettext('PASSWORD_REQUIRED')
        elif user['status'] == 'DEL':
            error = gettext('USER_DELETED')
        elif user['enabled'] == 0:
            error = gettext('USER_DISABLED')

        if error is None:
            session.clear()
            session['user_id'] = user['id']
            session['custom_id'] = ''
            session['user_name'] = user['username']
            return redirect(fallback)

        flash(error)

    return render_template('auth/login.html')
```

Before adding the decorator, the function works well. But now, with the following decorator :

```
def custom_overload(function, file,):
    filename = os.path.basename(file)
    configName = cfg(current_app.config['CONFIG_FILE'])
    Config = cfg(current_app.config['CONFIG_FOLDER'] + '/config_' + configName.cfg['PROFILE']['id'] + '.ini')

    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return redirect(url_for(function))
        return wrapper
return decorator
```

I have I have the following error :

`RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.`

I know this is the call of `current_app` but I don't understand why it's not working and what could I do to make it works

Thanks

Comment: did you try to use `app.app_context()` in you decorator?

Comment: Yes, the functions doesn't exist said PyCharm..